# Generar una lista con letras del abecedario, en PHP o JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

Quiero Generar un listado que lleve indice con letras, por ejemplo:
A.- lista
B.- lista
C.- lista
....
pero si el listado pasa la letra Z que genere asi:
AA.- lista
AB.- lista
AC.- lista

Espero puedan apoyarme.... Saludos!!!!

Comment: Necesitas hacerlo en javascript o en PHP o ambos

Comment: de preferencia en php...

Comment: Hola Jesús. Lastimosamente, este tipo de preguntas tan abiertas no se pueden realizar en el sitio. Sin embargo, puedes acceder al [salón de chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) donde esas preguntas son bienvenidas puesto que el chat es más informal y las personas cuentan sus opiniones sobre diversos temas. Solo haz click en el enlace de este comentario.

Comment: No le veo tan mal a la pregunta, quisas necesite una mejor redacción pero lo que busca se entiende claro, quiere generar nombres de listas en ves de numéricas que se llamen como los números de columna de una hoja de calculo.

Comment: Jesus Por favor agrega tu codigoa actual para que te podamos ayudar mejor

Comment: Ricardo D. Quiroga. me ayudo con una funcion, funciono perfecta. la funcion se encuentra en las respuesta. gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Esta funciona generanda simple y sencillo usando recursividad

```
function getExcelCol($num) {
    $numero = $num % 26;
    $letra = chr(65 + $numero);
    $num2 = intval($num / 26);
    if ($num2 > 0) {
        return getExcelCol($num2 - 1) . $letra;
    } else {
        return $letra;
    }
}
```

Comment: gracias ricardo, me funciono perfecto.

Comment: si soluciono tu problema califica la respuesta. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

ya no te debes preocupar por esto , PHP hace lo que tu quieres que haga

```
    <?php
        $miletra = "A";
        for ($i =0; $i < 30; $i++){
            echo $miletra."<br/>";
            $miletra++;
        }
?>
```